# Left join query in Django with multiple joins against same table

Tags: sql, django, join

Not sure how to accomplish this in Django.

Models:

```
class LadderPlayer(models.Model):
  player = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
  position = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

class Match(models.Model):
  date = models.DateTimeField() 
  challenger = models.ForeignKey(LadderPlayer)
  challengee = models.ForeignKey(LadderPlayer)
```

Would like to query to get all info about a player in one shot, including any challenges they have issued or challenges against them.  This SQL works:

```
select lp.position,
lp.player_id,
sc1.challengee_id challenging,
sc2.challenger_id challenged_by
from ladderplayer lp left join challenge sc1 on lp.player_id = sc1.challenger_id
left join challenge sc2 on lp.player_id = sc2.challengee_id
```

Which returns something like this, if player 3 has challenged player 2:

```
position    player_id   challenging  challenged_by
----------  ----------  -----------  -------------
1           1
2           2                        3
3           3           2
```

No idea how to do in Django ORM....any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you should probably change your models a bit, since there's a many-to-many relation from `LadderPlayer` to itself using `Match` as an *intermediate table*. Check out [django's documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) on this topic. Then you should be able to make the queries you want using django's orm! Also have a look at [symmetrical/asymmetrical many-to-many relationships](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/m2m_recursive/)!

Comment: He should be able to do the queries he wants using the Django ORM, regardless. But it's still good advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did more digging and it looks like in Django 1.2 this is doable via the "raw()" method on the Query Manager thing.  So this is the code using my query above:

```
ladder_players = LadderPlayer.objects.raw("""select lp.id, lp.position,lp.player_id,
sc1.challengee_id challenging,
sc2.challenger_id challenged_by
from ladderplayer lp left join challenge sc1 on lp.player_id = sc1.challenger_id
left join challenge sc2 on lp.player_id = sc2.challengee_id order by position""")
```

And in the template, you can refer to the "calculated" join fields:

```
{% for p in ladder_players %}
{{p.challenging}} {{p.challenged_by}}
...
```

etc.

Seems to work as I needed....

Comment: While using raw is always an option, since you can do this pretty easily via the Django ORM, it's probably better to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

@lazerscience is absolutely correct. You should tweak your models, since you are setting up a de facto many-to-many relationship; doing so will allow you to leverage more features of the admin interface & so forth.

Additionally, regardless, there is no need to go to `raw()`, since this can be done entirely via normal usage of the Django ORM.

Something like:

```
class LadderPlayer(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    position = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    challenges = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False, through='Match')

class Match(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField() 
    challenger = models.ForeignKey(LadderPlayer)
    challengee = models.ForeignKey(LadderPlayer)
```

should be all you need to change in the models. You then should be able to do a query like

```
player_of_interest = LadderPlayer.objects.filter(pk=some_id)
matches_of_interest = \
        Match.objects.filter(Q(challenger__pk=some_id)|Q(challengee__pk=some_id))
```

to get all the information of interest about the player in question. Note that you'll need to have `from django.db.models import Q` to use that.

If you want *exactly* the same info you're presenting with your example query, I believe it'd be easiest to split the queries into separate ones for getting the challenger & challengee lists -- for example, something like:

```
challengers = LadderPlayer.objects.filter(challenges__challengee__pk=poi_id)
challenged_by = LadderPlayer.objects.filter(challenges__challenger__pk=poi_id)
```

will get the two relevant query sets for the player of interest (w/ a primary key of `poi_id`).

If there's some particular reason you don't want the de facto many-to-many relationship to become a de jure one, you can change those to something along the lines of

```
challenger = LadderPlayer.objects.filter(match__challengee__pk=poi_id)
challenged_by = LadderPlayer.objects.filter(match__challenger_pk=poi_id)
```

So the suggestion for the model change is merely to help leverage existing tools, and to make explicit a relationship which you are currently having occur implicitly.

Based on how you want use it, you might want to do something like

```
pl_tuple = ()
for p in LadderPlayer.objects.all():
    challengers = LadderPlayer.objects.filter(challenges__challengee__pk=p.id)
    challenged_by = LadderPlayer.objects.filter(challenges__challenger__pk=p.id)
    pl_tuple += (p.id, p.position, challengers, challenged_by)
context_dict['ladder_players'] = pl_tuple
```

in your view to prepare the data for your template.

Regardless, you should probably be doing your query through the Django ORM instead of using `raw()` in this case.

Comment: Well the only reason where making a raw query would make sense in this example if you want to this with hitting the database only ONCE. django will not return objects in a many-to-many relation or reverse-foreign-key relation with ONLY ONE query!

Comment: True, but I think that's likely a premature optimization -- and since the questioner was asking how to do it via the ORM, I rather suspect that the choice to use `raw()` was made due to lack of experience w/ the ORM, rather than due to performance considerations.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, I will have to study it.  On initial glance, it doesn't seem right to me to have a challenges field in the LadderPlayer model.  "challenge" is not an attribute of a player.  Also, a player can only be in one single challenge at a time, as either a challenger or challengee.  So a challenge must have two players, and a player can be involved in 0 or 1 challenge...doesn't strike me as a traditional many-to-many situation.

Comment: @chacmool Are you only keeping challenges which haven't yet occurred in the database? If you're keeping all of them, then I'd say it *is* a straightforward, normal many-to-many situation; if you remove challenges from the DB after they've occurred, then I'd either use `OneToOneField` instead of `ForeignKey` in Match, or use `unique` or `unique_together` constraints in the `Match` model (and either way, skip the `ManyToManyField`). As for whether challenges are an attribute of a player, that has to do with how you think of the problem -- so if you don't think of them that way, then don't do it.

Comment: yes, only keeping unplayed/scheduled challenges in the db under that model.  I have another model for games played where "history" will be stored.  I should have specified that up front.  OneToOneField sounds like a good suggestion, will look into that.  Thanks for all the input.  I generally still think of solutions in a pure relational db/SQL mindest, hard to shift to ORM for me....thank you for the suggestions.